# ¿Cómo elimino datos con un script SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, delete

Lo que requiero es saber como puedo hacer para eliminar los registros que contengan las letras SMD, se que existe `LIKE '%SMD%'` pero como lo implementaría en esta búsqueda, ¿alguna idea? 
Estuve intentando con `DELETE * FROM c.equipos_detalles_id WHERE c.equipos_detalles_id LIKE '%SMD%'` pero no obtuve resultado.

**La eliminación debe ocurrir a la vez que se hace la búsqueda con `SELECT`**

Adjunto foto del Query[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quítale el asterisco a tu `DELETE`.

Comment: Intentas eliminar los registros que contengan la cadena SMD en el campo "c.equipos_detalles_id" pero el campo que muestra esa información es el campo "c.clave_id". Puede que sea eso.

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: @Cuauhtli en que parte debo colocar el `DELETE` ya quite el asterisco pero nomas no puedo ubicarlo correctamente en el query.

@track3r tienes razón. Ya hice esa corrección, gracias.

@Japv un error relacionado a la sintaxis, creo que se debía al asterisco y/o a donde lo tengo posicionado, no me queda muy claro donde colocar la sentencia `DELETE`.

Comment: Tu query esta bien, sólo quita el asterisco y ya. Te tiene que quedar como las respuesta que puse en esta publicación, sólo que aún no doy la explicación que merece. En un momento hago el update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta quitándole el asterisco a tu `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM c.equipos_detalles_id 
WHERE c.equipos_detalles_id LIKE '%SMD%'
```

Comment: ¿Por qué? La mínima explicación sería entregar el formato correcto de DELETE y explicar el significado del asterisco en SQL.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/301532)

Comment: @CandidMoe. Gracias. Totalmente de acuerdo. Lo escribí muy rápido sin dar explicaciones. Lo corregiré en unas horas.